# laravel how to get the extremities tables through the pivot

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

How do I from the middle table get to one of the two tables at the ends.

Ex: In the user_role table, from user_id I want to get the corresponding user.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89iFN.png)

thanks...

Comment: What exactly data you have already and what exactly do you want to get? You can't want to get just one user since pivot tables are used for many-to-many relationships.

Comment: Could you maybe provide example? Show some models you have already and present the problem you're having, that would help us helping you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have any one instance of the `User` or `Role`, you can get your relation. To get all roles of one user, you can perform this

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
    echo $role->operations;
}
```

The same way , to get all User of a Role, use this

```
$role = Role::find(1);

foreach ($role->users as $user) {
    echo $user->email;
}
```

You can found all the informations about this on Laravel Docs, see more on https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many